# Provable URL query not executing _callback?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, provable

I have a smart contract running on Ropstein testnet. It includes an HTTP call to a third-party API which responds with a JSON. However, the _callback function doesn't seem to be invoking for some reason. Any clues?
The relevant chunk of code:

```
function __callback(bytes32 queryId, string memory result) public override {
        emit APIResponse(result);
        if (msg.sender != provable_cbAddress()) revert();
        // rest of the code
    }

    function executeAPICall() private {
        if (provable_getPrice("URL") > msg.sender.balance) {
           emit Failure("Provable query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
        } else {
            emit OK("Trying to fetch API..");
            provable_query("URL", "json(http://ip).property");
        }
    }
```

I'm sure that the query (or, well, the blockchain-side of it) is getting executed as it logs the *OK* event, but there's no *APIResponse* event present. Does it perhaps require the API to be served over HTTPS?